# Unable to accept CA certificate though added to truststore

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, ca, truststore

I am having problem with accepting self signed CA certificate with java.

The problem is that in some situations the certificate is accepted and everything goes great. in another ones things are not so good.

As the steps I can describe the following.

I add the certificate to the truststore, reInit the SSLSocketFactory.
and the problem is that with one particular certificate and a particular environment this does not work. Everithing is Ok with other certificates acceptance.

The java version on machine on which it fails is 1.8.0_102.
My development machine is with java version 1.8.0_77.
Can this be an issue?

Any other thoughts on what can be the reason?

One more thing:
The failing certificate misses some fields like "Locality" "State of province".

Comment: Edit your question and add more details. What components do make still problems? How do you load your truststore and init the SSLSocketFactory (post your code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the certificate wasn't really added to the store.
After fixing the problem with addition everything works fine.